# Python's Min() for Custom Class (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was implementing a Binary Search tree and created a minimum method. I wanted to know how (or if) I can make it compatible so that I am able to do:

```
min(my_tree)
```

Instead of

```
my_tree.minimum()
```

I was thinking if it uses the iterator, it would be O(N) time instead of O(lgN).

Comment: It's not possible - `min()` is a function and cannot be overloaded for custom class. Internal implementation cannot exploit BST internal structure and therefore it's complexity won't be ever lower than O(n).

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in [**`bisect`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)?

Comment: @Rogalski `min`'s [**`key`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) parameter allows clever tricks.

Comment: @PeterWood won't `key` change just criteria function? `min` will still iterate over each entry in sequence and compare their criteria function values. Each item = O(n).

Comment: @Rogalski yes, you're right. `my_tree` would have to be iterable and produce something for linear search.

Comment: @Peterwood It doesn't even need to be iterable.  For example, the custom class could keep the current minimum element. In which case, I'd expect min(my_tree) to return in O(1).

Comment: @lorenzocastillo [**`min`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) expects an iterable when called with only one parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `min` in CPython can here found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/818989a48e96/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1345). The relevant code is repeated below.

```c
static PyObject *
min_max(PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds, int op)
{
    /* omitted code */
    it = PyObject_GetIter(v);
    /* omitted code */

    maxitem = NULL; /* the result */
    maxval = NULL;  /* the value associated with the result */
    while (( item = PyIter_Next(it) )) {
        /* get the value from the key function */
        if (keyfunc != NULL) {
            val = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(keyfunc, item, NULL);
            if (val == NULL)
                goto Fail_it_item;
        }
        /* no key function; the value is the item */
        else {
            val = item;
            Py_INCREF(val);
        }

        /* maximum value and item are unset; set them */
        if (maxval == NULL) {
            maxitem = item;
            maxval = val;
        }
    /* more omitted code */
    }
}

static PyObject *
builtin_min(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return min_max(args, kwds, Py_LT);
}
```

From this, it can be seen that using `min` is going to be O(n) no matter what; it passes through each member in the iterable. You are not able to override this behavior and I don't think your current usage of `tree.minimum()` is unnatural at all.

Comment: I was thinking maybe implement a min_iter, max_iter, etc, or something along those, but that seemed very convoluted when Python usually has something cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* write your own function called `min` and use it to hide the fact that it isn't really possible:

```
min_ = min
def min(*args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(args[0], MyTree):
        return args[0].minimum()
    else:
        return min_(*args, **kwargs)
```

Don't do this, though.